# How can I measure -170 dB GPS signal with a spectrum analyzer?

Tags: signal, measurement, gps, spectrum-analyzer

I'm looking for a way to measure noise signals (probably MCU harmonics) that affect the performance of my GPS receiver (Ubox sam-m8q-0-10.) Can anyone point me to the right direction?

I own a spectrum analyzer up to 3 GHz, a set of magnetic field + electric field probes. Can anyone suggest documentation on how to use my hardware in order to find the noise?

Comment: do you have a RF signal generator? if you have one, you can measure a higher power level signal (-130 or -100 dB) and observe the final output of your circuit till the LNA. -170 dB is challenging i feel.

Comment: Is the -170 dB with reference to watts or milli watts or volts or amps or sub variants? "dB" without some extra information is meaningless as an absolute level.

Comment: Hello @User323693 . I don't have an RF generator. I have some LNAs though. I have thought of amplifying the signal in order to be able to see it with my spectrum but because I'm kind of inexperienced I have to study before using the HW in order to avoid destroying something.

Comment: Hello @Andyaka . I would like to measure the electric and magnetic field with my spectrum analyzer. My analyzer is in dBuV if I'm not mistaken. I would like to find which is the "noisy" part and then find a way to reduce it's electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: You didn't understand did you. Think about what I asked in my comment.

Comment: @Andyaka it will be in m Watts.. i think he meant -170dBm.

Comment: @User323693 guesswork?

Comment: I'm sorry you are right I didn't understand. It is -170dBm as @User323693 mentioned above.

Comment: -174dBm is the thermal noise floor for a 1Hz bandwidth at 300K (27C). Although there are ways to measure signals below that, I doubt your spectrum analyser can do so.

Answer (score -1):

I think -130 dBm is the level received on the Earth's surface and it is very low level. Moreover, the GPS signal is DSSS which cannot be display on the spectrum analyzer directly because it is always below the noise floor.

Comment: It is true that the GNSS signal is spread spectrum and below the noise floor, but the questioner is looking to measure the noise signal not the GNSS signal.